# PHP Search for a keyword from a text file, prints the whole line with the keyword, then counts how many lines were printed

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP and I was trying to print certain lines with a specific keyword, and make the program count the lines printed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
// LOOKS FOR "ERR:" IN THE LOG AND PRINTS THE WHOLE LINE.
$file = 'Sample.log';
$searchfor = 'ERR:';
$lines = 0;

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Lines found with the keyword " . "\"" . $searchfor . "\"" . "\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
   while (! feof($file))
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
?>
```

(the code was originally made by Lekensteyn, I just modified it to my liking - https://stackoverflow.com/users/427545/lekensteyn)
It prints all the the lines in the text file with the keyword "ERR:", but I want the code to print the lines with the keyword "ERR:" (done) and output below the lines printed (count the lines printed) "Total lines printed with the keyword **\"ERR:**": "

EDIT: I tried putting this below echo(implode) :
    echo "\nTotal lines printed: " . count($matches);
But it only outputs 1. Help

Comment: Total matches is just `count($matches)`.

Comment: Mike, can you please elaborate where would I exactly put the count($matches) with the complete code. Thank you!

Comment: I tried inserting it right after echo implode like this:

Comment: count($matches);
 echo "Total lines printed: " . $matches;
it prints the files but it shows this after the printed lines:
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\LogTest.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
Total lines printed: Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is essentially a one liner that may work:

```
$array  =   array_filter(array_map(function($v){
    return (stripos($v,'ERR:') !== false)? $v : false; 
},array_filter(file('Sample.log',FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES),function($v){
    return (!empty(trim($v)));
})));
# This will implode the lines
echo (!empty($array))? implode('<br />',$array) : '';
# This will count the array
echo ((!empty($array))? count($array) : 0).' matches found.';
```

First it uses `file()` to turn a file into an array using new lines, then filters empty lines that may exist, then uses `array_map()` to iterate, then inside that uses `stripos()` to search each line for `ERR:`, then returns the ones that match (or `false` if no match), then `array_filter()` with no callback to remove all the values with `false` (empty). The last two lines implode the remaining array and then writes how many values are in the final array using `count()`.